# Let $f(x) =x+\tan^3x $ and $g(x) =f^{-1}(x)$ then find the value of ...

Tags: calculus, functions

Problem :

Let $f(x) = x + \tan^3 x $ and $g(x) =f^{-1}(x)$ then find the value of 
$56g'(\frac{\pi}{4}+1)$

My approach :

$f'(x) = 1+3\tan^2x \sec^2x$

$f'(\frac{\pi}{4})=7$

now how to find $g'(\frac{\pi}{4}+1)$

Please guide not getting any clue on this.

Comment: There is a general formula for the derivative of an inverse function which tells you that $g'(\pi/4 + 1) = 1/f'(g(\pi/4 + 1))$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that, by definition of an inverse function:

$f(g(x))=x$

Then:

$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x))=1$

$f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)=1$ (by the Chain Rule)

And, as @Alex G. pointed out:

$g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$

So, then it should follow immediately that:

$g'(\frac{π}{4}+1)=\frac{1}{f'(g(1+\frac{π}{4}))}$

And then just do the calculations...

EDIT: Sure enough, trying some stereotypical tangent values works. In this case we find that:

$g(\frac{π}{4}+1)=\frac{π}{4}$

So, therefore:

$g'(\frac{π}{4}+1)=\frac{1}{f'(\frac{π}{4})}$

$f'(\frac{π}{4})=1+3\tan(\frac{π}{4})\sec^2(\frac{π}{4})=1+3\sec^2(\frac{π}{4})=7$

So your answer is then, $g'(\frac{π}{4}+1)=\frac{1}{7}$